# Is the sum of this $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}$ defined at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I found that the sum of the following series :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!} = \frac{2}{x}(e^\frac{x}{2}-1)$$

I know that that for any $x \neq 0 \rightarrow f(x)=\frac{2}{x}(e^\frac{x}{2}-1)$

But for $x=0$ the function is not defined, If I use the series I get 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{0^k}{2^k(k+1)!}=0 (k\neq0)$$

So can I get that $f(0)=0$ from the series? It doesn't seems right to me.

I think I missing something, I'll be glad if someone could help clear this matter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first term, $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: No, it's fine, just take it to be 1 because $x^0=1$ for all the other x's...

Comment: @Theo I'd say it is $\lim_{x\to 0} x^0 = 1$, and also $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 1$, but $f(0)$ itself is not defined unless you special-case the limit point.

Comment: @kennytm The point here is not the function is defined or not... It is that it can be continuously -analytically for that matter- extended to contain 0. The confusion is created because he thought the summation on the left evaluates to 0 at 0 (which it doesn't). The function on the RHS has limit 1 at 0 which can be deduced either from Del Hospital or from the series description on the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the series should be more properly written as
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{x}(e^\frac{x}{2}-1) & \text{if $x\ne0$}\\
1 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
A function which is the sum of a power series is differentiable in the whole (open) circle of convergence.

For $x=0$ the sum of the series is $1$, as $0^0=1$ (don't trust who says it's not defined).

---

You can consider the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = e^y-1
$$
and you have
$$
x\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}=2(e^{x/2}-1)
$$
for all $x$. So, by continuity, you have that the sum of the series for $x=0$ is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x/2}-1}{x/2}=1
$$

Comment: Well..., in general it's not defined, as for instance $\big( \frac{1}{n^n}\big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 0$ but in this case you are absolutely right...

Comment: @Theo Here it is *not* a limit: it's just raising to *the integer $0$*, which is perfectly defined to be $1$ for all numbers.

Comment: @egreg I understand that $x^k$ is differentiable in the whole open circle of convergence, but how can you conclude that $0^0=1$?

Comment: @JaVaPG Because $x^0$ is defined to be $1$ for all numbers $x$. If you prefer, this is the convention used when dealing with power series; for instance $e^x=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n/n!$: for $x=0$ you get $0^0$, don't you?

Comment: @egreg yeah, yeah, of course... I just wanted to indicate the dangers of writing something like $0^0=1$... If you see my comment in the question above, you'll notice I am saying the same thing as you...

Comment: Actually, I didn't knew about this convention, Learned something new:) Thank you both :)

Comment: @egreg One last thing if you can, why is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k(k+1)!}=0?$$

Comment: @JaVaPG Why should it be?

Comment: @egreg If I understood correctly, the reason that $f(0)=1$ is because we know that the function is continuous  and therefore the limit is equal to 1 so we can conclude that f(0)=1 (because since it's continuous we know that f(0)=1)  true?

Comment: @JaVaPG Not really: the series, computed for $x=0$, is $1+0+0+\dotsb$ *by definition* (because $0^0=1$).

Comment: I find this part hard to understand, I'm sorry for so many questions, I know that $e^x=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n/n!$ for x=0 we get $0^0+0+0+0+0.....=1+0+0+0+0+....$ by definition however in this case our series is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}$ for x=0 we get $\frac{1}{2^0(0+1)!}=1+\frac{1}{2^1(1+1)!}+....$ which is not $1$.

Comment: @JaVaPG $0^1=0^2=\dots=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one can define $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x) = f(0) = 1$, which follows both by direct substition into the series and using l'Hospital's rule for the closed form expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first term of the series (for $k=0$) is just $1$, not $x^0$ (which you might be tempted to interpret as $0^0=0$ at $x=0$).

Comment: I need to find that $f(0)$ I don't understand what $k=0$ has to do with that?

Comment: All other terms vanish. $1+x/4+x^2/24+\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit formula for
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}
$
doesn't matter.
What matters is that
the series is absolutely convergent
everywhere in the finite complex plane.

The good old ratio test 
works just fine here.

$\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}
=\dfrac{\frac{x^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}(k+2)!}}{\frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}}
=\dfrac{x}{2(k+2)}
\to 0
$
as $k \to \infty$
for any finite $x$.